# Probability of one defective tablet and at least non-defective iPad

Tags: probability, statistics

A big department store receives 80 tablets out of which 10 are defective. Out of the remaining 70 working models, 30 are Samsung and 40 are Apple iPads. If 5 are selected randomly from the pool of 80 tablets, what is the probability that exactly one is broken and at least 3 are working (not-defective) iPads?

I made two separate cases and added them together: first, the probability of getting one detective tablet, then multiplying it by the probability of getting 3 iPads, and then one tablet(10/80 * (40/70 * 39/69 * 38/68) * 30/70). Repeat for the second case, where there is one defective tablet and 4 working iPads: (10/80 * (40/70 * 39/69 * 38/68 *37/67)).

So, the answer I got was (10/80 * (40/70 * 39/69 * 38/68) * 30/70) + (10/80 * (40/70 * 39/69 * 38/68 *37/67)) = 1235/5581 = .022%. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

*Exactly 1* is broken and *exactly 4* are working. Of the 4, at least 3 need to be iPads.

The number of ways exactly 1 is broken = $^{10}C_1$

From the remaining 4 that are working, in how many ways can there be at least 3 iPads?
$^{30}C_0 \times ^{40}C_4 + ^{30}C_1 \times ^{40}C_3 = I$ [The maximum number of Samsung cell phones is 1]

The total number of ways we can get exactly 1 defective and at least 3 iPads
in the 5 selected = $^{10}C_1 \times I = D$

The probability of getting exactly 1 defective and at least 3 iPads = $\frac{D}{^{80}C_5}$

... I think